# How to Query in a many to many relationship Room database?

Tags: android, sql, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a many to many relationship Room database with three tables:

First one :

```
data class Name(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var nameId : Long = 0L,
@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
var name : String = "",
@ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
var notes: String=""
)
```

Second:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tags_table")
data class Tag(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var tagId : Long = 0L,
@ColumnInfo(name = "tag_name")
var tagName : String = ""
)
```

Third:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "tagInName_table",
    primaryKeys = ["nameId", "tagId"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Name::class,
            parentColumns = ["nameId"],
            childColumns = ["nameId"]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Tag::class,
            parentColumns = ["tagId"],
            childColumns = ["tagId"]
        )
    ]
)
data class TagInName(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nameId")
    var nameId: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tagId")
    var tagId: Long = 0L

)
```

The data class I use for a return object in a Query:

```
data class NameWithTags(
    @Embedded
    val name: Name,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "nameId",
        entityColumn = "tagId",
        associateBy = Junction(value = TagInName::class)
    )
    val listOfTag : List<Tag>
)
```

This is how I query to get all NamesWithTags:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM names_table")
@Transaction
fun getNamesWithTags() : LiveData<List<NameWithTags>>
```

**So the thing I need to do is, I need to Query to return `LiveData<List<NameWithTags>>` where every NamesWithTags has a list which contains the Tag ID that I Query for.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my interpretation of what you say you need to do, then :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT names_table.* FROM names_table JOIN tagInName_table ON names_table.nameId = tagInName_table.nameId JOIN tags_table ON tagInName_table.tagId = tags_table.tagId WHERE tags_table.tagId=:tagId ")
fun getNameWithTagsByTagId(tagId: Long): LiveData<List<NamesWithTags>>
```

- ***Note** the above is in-principle code and has not been compiled or tested, so it may contain some errors.*
- A NameWithTags will contain ALL related tags whcih should be fine according to (where every NamesWithTags has a list which contains the Tag ID ), if you wanted just certain Tags in the List of Tags then it's a little more complex, this is explained in a recent answer at  [Android Room query with condition for nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150325/android-room-query-with-condition-for-nested-object/73158752#73158752)

Comment: Is there a way to delete a entry from Name table and from tagInName table with a query

Comment: @FarisRizvanović when defining the ForeignKeys use the onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, this, if you delete a Name or Tag will cascade the deletion of the children (in the TagInName table). Otherwise, if there are children then such a deletion would fail due to the FK conflict. The alternative would be to do this in stages deleting the children (in the TagInName table) and then deleting the parent. (see next comment)

Comment: @FarisRizvanović When you define a ForeignKey, which isn't required (but advised) you are not defining the relationship but  are defining a constraint(rule) that says that the child column MUST be a value that exists in the parent column. As such the Foreign Key enforces referential integrity and in the case of CASCADE (onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE and or onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE) maintains the referential integrity by either deleting the children or updating the children's column value when the parent is deleted or updated. (see next comment)

Comment: @FarisRizvanović Lastly, if you look at the build you will be warned about having an index on the Tagid column of the TagInName table. You could change `@ColumnInfo(name = "tagId")` to be `@ColumnInfo(name = "tagId, index = true")`. This would make accessing the intermediate (associative/reference/mapping table (and other names)) via the TagId more efficient (at the cost of some additional storage though). see https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html for further explanation of Foreign Keys.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you for taking your time and explaining everything in detail.